# How do you copy-paste from PDF to google drive?

Tags: pdf, copy-paste

I have tried numerous times to copy and paste text from a PDF into Notepad or Google Drive and a bunch of random line breaks get added. How do you do it? I really don't want to instal a whole other program for such a simple task.

Comment: I believe you can directly upload the PDF file and have Google convert  the document to a *Google Doc* format. Otherwise, use a converter to convert it into a *Word* document.

Answer (score 1):

Might be that the file is protected somehow? Normally you'd just highlight the text and use <kbd>CRTL</kbd>**+**<kbd>C</kbd> to grab what you want.

Otherwise, there are online tools such as [Online OCR](http://www.onlineocr.net) that will "scan" the PDF file and output it to a Word doc, which you can then upload straight to Google Docs, or open and copy what you want.